# Unity3d and Android 5.0+ device owner application

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, device-owner

Is there any possibility to make unity3d application use new possibilities in Android 5.0 device owner app?

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#DeviceOwner

I'm trying to make app in unity3d that will work in "kiosk mode".

Comment: a great tip, did not know about it.  I imagine you'd do that in the Manifest

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about Unit3d but if it is a regular apk you probably can make use of DeviceOwner features. Though, enabling DeviceOwner is not a task for regular user on regular apps.

First, it requires the device to not have being provisioned - most common scenarios there is no account setup in the device. The process can be done either through a second device using NFC and a provisioning app or via `adb shell dpm set-device-owner app.package/.DeviceAdminReceiver`... not trivial, neither can be done by regular end users. May be what you want is just full screen mode? That can be done in the manifest... Kiosk mode will actually pin your app in the device.

If you are willing for setting up an actual kiosk to demo your app or something similar, it is indeed a good direction to go.